# C++ memcpy and happy access violation

Tags: c++, access-violation, memcpy

For some reason i can't figure i am getting access violation.

```
memcpy_s (buffer, bytes_per_line * height, image, bytes_per_line * height);
```

This is whole function:

```
int Flip_Bitmap(UCHAR *image, int bytes_per_line, int height)   
{   
    // this function is used to flip bottom-up .BMP images   

    UCHAR *buffer; // used to perform the image processing   
    int index;     // looping index   

    // allocate the temporary buffer   
    if (!(buffer = (UCHAR *) malloc (bytes_per_line * height)))   
        return(0);   

    // copy image to work area   
    //memcpy(buffer, image, bytes_per_line * height);   
    memcpy_s (buffer, bytes_per_line * height, image, bytes_per_line * height);

    // flip vertically   
    for (index = 0; index < height; index++)   
        memcpy(&image[((height - 1) - index) * bytes_per_line], &buffer[index * bytes_per_line], bytes_per_line);   

    // release the memory   
    free(buffer);   

    // return success   
    return(1);   

} // end Flip_Bitmap
```

Whole code:
http://pastebin.com/udRqgCfU

To run this you'll need 24-bit bitmap, in your source directory.
This is a part of a larger code, i am trying to make Load_Bitmap_File function to work...
So, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `image` has the advertised size? And that the two size parameters are passed correctly?

Comment: You don't need that temporary buffer

Comment: I believe the problem is with `image` - it's just not `bytes_per_line * height`.

Comment: Is it a read or write access violation?

Comment: compare `biSizeImage` with the size you calculate with `bytes_per_line * height`. report us back

Comment: @Bo Persson: It's happy... :) Martin: Sorry for the pun.

Comment: @yi_H you are correct. `biSizeImage == bytes_per_line * height` is `0 == 1003008`. Maybe i copied data wrongly...

Comment: @Bo: read. `Unhandled exception at 0x61e5be4b (msvcr100d.dll) in Test_ifstream_read.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x005a6000.`

Comment: @Martin - If it's reading, there is nothing wrong with the `buffer`, but the amount of data copied. I see from the other comments that you are checking that. Will hopefully solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting an access violation because **a lot of image programs don't set `biSizeImage` properly**.  The image you're using probably has `biSizeImage` set to 0, so you're not allocating any memory for the image data (in reality, you're probably allocating 4-16 bytes, since most `malloc` implementations will return a non-`NULL` value even when the requested allocation size is 0).  So, when you go to copy the data, you're reading past the ends of that array, which results in the access violation.

Ignore the `biSizeImage` parameter and compute the image size yourself.  Keep in mind that the size of each scan line must be a multiple of 4 bytes, so you need to round up:

```
// Pseudocode
#define ROUNDUP(value, power_of_2) (((value) + (power_of_2) - 1) & (~((power_of_2) - 1)))
bytes_per_line = ROUNDUP(width * bits_per_pixel/8, 4)
image_size = bytes_per_line * height;
```

Then just use the same image size for reading in the image data and for flipping it.

Comment: That's it. Manual calculation of image size works. Main program functions, although wrongly, the image is stretched across whole screen, but at least Load_Image_Function works. And can you please tell me what is operator `~` you have used? What it is supposed to do? I'd really like to understand `#define ROUNDUP(value, power_of_2) (((value) + (power_of_2) - 1) & (~((power_of_2) - 1)))`. THANKS for helping~

Comment: @Martin: The `~` operator is the unary bitwise negation operator.  It flips all 0's to 1's and vice-versa, so ~00110101 = 11001010 (in binary).  ~(4-1) is 0xFFFFFFFC, so `ROUNDUP(x, 4)` is equivalent to `((x + 3) & 0xFFFFFFFC)`, which rounds `x` up to the next multiple of 4 by adding 3 and the ANDing out the bottom two bits.

Comment: alright, thanks for clarification. Although i still can't understand why you need this function when `width * bits_per_pixel/8` is the same as `ROUNDUP(width * bits_per_pixel/8, 4)`.. I guess some precaution against something. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Martin: If `width` is 7 and `bits_per_pixel` is 24, then `width * bits_per_pixel/8` is 21, and `ROUNDUP(width * bits_per_pixel/8, 4)` is 24.  The number of bytes in a scan line is always a multiple of 4 in BMP files, so there are 24 bytes per scan line, not 21.

Comment: Ok. So that means that 24 - 21 = 3, and what is with that 3 stray bytes? 

Is that a stride, as Martin Beckett from below commented? 7 pixels * 24 bits per pixel / 8 bits = 21 byte. And ROUNDUP returns 24. So 3 bytes hang somewhere... 

And Adam, sorry if i am annoying, i just like these things :)

Comment: @Martin: The 3 stray bytes are [padding bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_padding).  They exist purely to make accesses to scan line data aligned with the processor's natural word alignment, which is many situations gives better performance.  The actual values of the padding bytes is completely ignored -- their values in memory or on disk has no affect whatsoever on the pixel data or anything else related to the image.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have said, the image data is not necessarily width*height*bytes_per_pixel

Memory access is generally faster on 32bit boundaries and when dealing with images speed generally matters. Because of this the rows of an image are often shifted to start on a 4byte (32bit) boundary

If the image pixels are 32bit (ie RGBA) this isn't a problem but if you have 3bytes per pixel (24bit colour) then for certain image widths, where the number of columns * 3 isn't a multiple of 4, then extra blank bytes will be inserted at the edn of each row.

The image format probably has a "stride" width or elemsize value to tell you this.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate `bitmap->bitmapinfoheader.biSizeImage` for `image` but proceed to copy `bitmap->bitmapinfoheader.biWidth * (bitmap->bitmapinfoheader.biBitCount / 8) * bitmap->bitmapinfoheader.biHeight` bytes of data. I bet the two numbers aren't the same.

Comment: You are right. `bitmap->bitmapinfoheader.biSizeImage` is 0... Who would expect that from MS PAINT? :)